# Batch Script :Capture only few characters in a string

Tags: batch-file

I want to capture 'yes' or 'no' from the below output,can someone help me to do this.

String is like below:
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No

currently my script is printing the ouput of
netsh interface ip show addresses ^| findstr "DHCP Enabled"

the output is below:
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No

i am stuck here on how to just print 'yes' or 'no' from the output

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know what you have tried before but you can try this script and see if it works:

```
@echo off

REM Run the command and capture the output
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('netsh interface ip show addresses ^| findstr "DHCP Enabled"') do set "output=%%A"

REM Use regular expressions to extract 'yes' or 'no'
for /F "tokens=3" %%B in ('echo %output% ^| findstr /R /C:"DHCP Enabled\. . . . . . . . . . . :.*Yes" /C:"DHCP Enabled\. . . . . . . . . . . :.*No"') do set "dhcp_enabled=%%B"

REM Convert the extracted value to lowercase for comparison
set "dhcp_enabled=%dhcp_enabled: =%"
set "dhcp_enabled=%dhcp_enabled: =%"

REM Print the result
if "%dhcp_enabled%"=="yes" (
    echo yes
) else if "%dhcp_enabled%"=="no" (
    echo no
) else (
    echo Could not determine DHCP status
)
```

Comment: I tried to run the script ,and print the output of variables %output and %dhcp_enabled .
it does not capture any value in dhcp_enabled variable
therefore its returning "Could not determine DHCP status"

Comment: your "convert to lowercase" doesn't work, it just removes spaces (which is actually important here) Converting to lowercase is not needed when you use `if /i`

Comment: Even the regular expression is also not returning any value 
Not very sure of any syntax error.

REM Use regular expressions to extract 'yes' or 'no'

for /F "tokens=3" %%B in ('echo %output% ^| findstr /R /C:"DHCP Enabled\. . . . . . . . . . . :.*Yes" /C:"DHCP Enabled\. . . . . . . . . . . :.*No"') do set "dhcp_enabled=%%B"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of actually extracting the word from the string, you can just test if `Yes` is part of the string or not (as it is either `Yes` or `No`)

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "string= DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No"
echo %string%|find /i "Yes" && set "result=Yes" || set "result=No"
echo DCHP enabled: %result%
```

Note: judging by the format of the string, it's probably from `ipconfig /all`. Be careful - the output of this command is language dependent and there can be more than one network adapter (with different settings).